# iPhone X iOS upgrade failed, now in recovery mode

Tags: iphone, ios

### Steps that lead to iPhone X being in recovery mode

- Phone runs out of battery and dies
- Phone put on charge and left alone
- Presumably that automatical tried to update to 13.3.1
- After some time (10-15 minutes) saw that it got stuck on apple logo with black screen
- Did force restart
- Got stuck at it again
- Put in recovery mode
- Connected to PC and attempted to update via iTunes
- Through iTunes update started, saw on iPhone apple logo and bar indicating that it was loading
- Around 15% of that bar iTunes shows error 14

Tried different tools, even bough one that **SHOULD'VE** fix it but did not.

Now attempting to update to iOS 13

**Goal**
Copy media files (image, videos) from iPhone (there are no backups) so that i could do factory reset.

Any tips ?

Comment: Have you tried a different usb cable and different usb port when connected to iTunes?  Error 14 is due to something wrong with the usb connection.

Comment: yes, i have another usb cable and tried different usb port, both on MAC and PC. Still error 14 is showing.

Comment: Do you have any problems charging the iPhone?  I'm thinking that error is not the cable or the computer but it's the lightning port on the iPhone.

Comment: there have been no issues with charging it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to restore if you have not made a backup.
If you only want to retrieve certain files, try [this](https://www.ibeesoft.com/recover-iphone/recover-data-from-wiped-iphone.html) or one of [these tools.](https://www.ibeesoft.com/recover-iphone/best-free-iphone-data-recovery.html) They let you choose PHOTos and Vids to recover.

[1](https://www.ibeesoft.com/recover-iphone/recover-data-from-wiped-iphone.html)

Comment: The OP didn't ask to do a restore, but to copy off some files.  You answer may be technically accurate, but it doesn't directly address the OP's question.

Comment: What Files do you want to recover, I M